# jQuery slider from json feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, slider

I am trying to create a slider that will display daily specials for a restaurant. I have a json (or xml) feed that I grab the data from (its from wordpress). I'm able to get the data into an array and log it to the console but I can't figure out how to loop over the array and display the content one by one.

This is the script:

```
var content = new Array();
$.getJSON("http://riverdalecornercafe.com/wp/category/isd/feed/json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        content.push(item.content);
    });
console.log(content[0]);
});
```

html:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have JSON data, it's really simple. you can use ajax to execute your query :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://riverdalecornercafe.com/wp/category/isd/feed/json",
        success: function(jsonArray) {
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)
            {
               $('.content').append(/*the format you want to add in html */ json value : 'jsonArray[i].name)
            }


     error: function()
         {
            you can handle your error
          }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop for your json items.
Having the last item of your json you can go one by one.

eg

```
$.getJSON("http://riverdalecornercafe.com/wp/category/isd/feed/json", function(data) {
   var myJson = data;
   var lastItem = myJson.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < lastItem; i++){
      $('.content').append(myJson[i].title);
   }
});
```

latest update

```
<script type="text/javascript" text="javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://riverdalecornercafe.com/wp/category/isd/feed/json", function (data) {
        var myJson = data;
        var lastItem = myJson.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < lastItem; i++) {
            $('.innerCarousel').css('width', (lastItem * 500) + 'px');
            $('.innerCarousel').html("<div style=float:left;width:500px;><img src='" + myJson[i].imagePath + "' /></div>");
        }
    });
    $('.next').on('click', function () {
        $('.innerCarousel').animate({ left: ($(this).css('left') - 500) + "px" },"medium");
    });
    $('.prev').on('click', function () {
        $('.innerCarousel').animate({ left: ($(this).css('left') + 500) + "px" }, "medium");
    });
</script>


<div style="width:500px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
    <div class="innerCarousel" style="position:absolute;left:0px;"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the json data and load it into the array but my question was how to iterate over the array and display the contents one by one, similar to an image slider.

Comment: You can bind all the images inside a div with overflow hidden and make some sliding(animation) inside, or you can simple call the next element from the array. i can send you code if you want

Comment: Thanks R0ger, I would love to see the code, Im not that good with JavaScript yet so I have to learn by trying and failing.